# Do the novels explain the sudden "hair change" near the end of Gosick?

Tags: gosick

Near the end of the Gosick anime (possibly even just the last episode, I can't remember)... Victorique's hair suddenly changes from gold to silver.

There was speculation about whether this was an intended dye job to hide her identity or representative of her sadness.

Do the original novels give a clear explanation or is it just as ambiguous?

Comment: I don't think there is a no clear answer. It's speculated that it was either the result of Victorique dying it (because she heard they were looking for a blonde girl) or whitened due to stress (see [Marie-Anotinette Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie_Antoinette_syndrome)).

Comment: @Krazer I saw that Wiki mentioned that syndrome on the Gosick page, but it did not provide a citation... So I wasn't sure if it was just speculation or something actually explained in the novels.

Comment: I don't recall it being mentioned in the light novels, both theories are just speculations made by fans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was neither stated in the manga or in the anime, nor the author revealed the reason in an interview/etc, but the most common explanation is the Marie-Antoinette-Syndrome. It's also written in the Wikipedia-article as a fact, but actually, it was never officially said, why the hair changes.

Answer (score 5):

There was a Q&A session with the anime director on the Twitter regarding the last episode of *GOSICK* in July 2011, and one of the question was about the changing in hair color:

> @namimi_sanjyo: アニメ版GOSICKの質問をいただいてます。少しお答えしますね。お付き合いよろしくです。
>   「最終回でヴィクトリカの髪が銀髪になったのはストレスからなのか？それとも自ら脱色したか？」です。
>   hyankhさん　GNT_0000さん　からいただきました。続く #gosick
>
> @namimi_sanjyo: ずばり！銀髪になったのは演出意図です。って答えじゃないかｗ
>   コルデリアやブライアンの死のショックで自然と色が抜けたのですが、
>   彼女の心象を表すためにも色を変えました。
>   ヴィクトリカは金色の妖精でもあり、
>   その金色でなくなることは妖精ではなくなった事も意味しました。
>   ショックぐらいで色が変わるはずがないと思うでしょうが、私の中でヴィクトリカは妖精でした。
>   いにしえの生き物です！
>   その彼女が力を失い人間になっていく過程（命乞いをするとか）が、あの逃亡中におこったのです！
>   その表現として髪の色も変わったと思って下さいませ。 #gosick

Rough translation

> @namimi_sanjyo: [...] "Was the reason for Victorique's hair color changing to silver due to the stress? Or was it losing color naturally? [...]
>
> @namimi_sanjyo: [...]. The color naturally lost due to the shock from Cordelia and Brian's death, but it's also changed to express her mind. Since Victorique is also "The Golden Fairy", her hair not being golden means that she is not "The Fairy" anymore. While I don't think that it's possible for hair to change color due to shock, she is still a "Fairy" in my mind. An ancient creature! The process (begging to die) when she lost the power and became a human being happened while running away! Please think that as the expression by the change of her hair color.

Ironically, as it has been mentioned by [looper](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/2046/2516) & [кяαzєя](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/233/do-the-novels-explain-the-sudden-hair-change-near-the-end-of-gosick#comment312_233), [Marie Antoinette syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marie_Antoinette_syndrome) actually exists. Also unfortunately, I failed to locate the tweets directly. Either they have been deleted or not indexed.

---

Source: [Otanews (Japanese)](http://otanews.livedoor.biz/archives/51803967.html)